# JavaScript: Same code take different time to execute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, execute

First i run this (in chrome):

```
var start;
var end;

start = (new Date()).getTime();

for(var i=0;i<10e5;i++);

end = (new Date()).getTime();

console.log('delay:' + (end-start));
```

Output: **`delay:2028`**
Then I run this:

```
function foo() {
    var start;
    var end;

    start = (new Date()).getTime();

    for(var i=0;i<10e5;i++);

    end = (new Date()).getTime();

    console.log('delay:' + (end-start));
}

foo();
```

Output: **`delay:8`**

Why took the same code shorter time when wrappered in a function?

*In node it took the same time (6 and 6), but node uses the V8 engine by the chrome isn't it?*

Comment: [For me](http://jsfiddle.net/2747F/) in Chrome it varies between 1 and 2, 1 and 1, and 2 and 1.

Comment: paste your code in the Console directly. I guess the jsfiddle do something "function wrappering" and that ruins the example.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! Ignore me then. (I get 897, 2 in the console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fact that this behavior only appears in the console is extremely telling. I suspect it has to do with how the V8 engine reducing the script down to native code.

**Point #1:** I suspect that scope is *not* the cause of the slowdown:

```
function foo() {
    start = (new Date()).getTime();
    for(i=0;i<10e5;i++);
    end = (new Date()).getTime();
    console.log('delay:' + (end-start));
}
```

This code uses `start`, `end`, and `i` in the global scope. If searching through the global scope really was the bottleneck, then this code should also run slowly, because it has no local variables in the function.

**Point #2:** If you put your code in an actual web page, it runs very quickly either way.  This suggests to me that *running code in the console* is the source of the slowdown.

Ordinarily, on a web page, the V8 engine assembles JavaScript into native binary code so it runs very quickly.  However, I suspect that code run from the console is not compiled (or is perhaps compiled line-by-line as it is run, which itself incurs a time cost).  When a *function definition* is entered, though, the function is compiled, in its entirety, before it is run for the first time. By the time the program flow reaches the `foo()` call, the function `foo` has already been compiled into native code. Thus the function runs quickly because it has been pre-compiled, but the raw code in the console has not been pre-compiled, so it runs slowly.

**This is largely speculation**, but so is every answer to this question.  This is the only explanation I can possibly devise that accounts for both points #1 and #2 above.

Comment: "Ordinarily, on a web page, the V8 engine assembles" - just nit picking... there is a world outside of chrome :)

Comment: @rlemon I'll admit I'm guilty of being a bit Chrome-centric sometimes (I'm trying hard to break the habit... :)), but here the OP mentioned that he's observing this behavior specifically in Chrome (`First i run this (in chrome)...`), so I'm addressing why this behavior would appear specifically in V8.

Comment: and that speculation can explain, why no difference in node.

Answer (score 3):

Because in function all your variables in closure. Without function JavaScript interpreter try to find your variables in Global scope first.

Comment: I suspect this might not be the whole story.  If I move the `start`, `end`, and `i` variable declarations outside the function to the global scope, I still see the speed difference.  If your explanation is true (and I'm not saying you're wrong!), why does the performance difference still exist when all the variables are global?